# Pass currently logged in username as an argument to reverse_lazy in class based view

Tags: python, django

```
@method_decorator([login_required, audience_required], name='dispatch')
class AudienceInterestsView(UpdateView):
    model = Audience
    form_class = AudienceInterestsForm
    template_name = 'interests_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profiledisp')

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user.audience

    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request, 'Interests updated with success!')
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

This is my code. I want to pass the currently logged in user's username as a parameter to the `profiledisp` view.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the user when you set `success_url` - that code runs when the module is loaded, so you don't have access to the request yet.

You can override [`get_success_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url) instead. Inside the method, you have access to the request and the logged in user.

```
class AudienceInterestsView(UpdateView):
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('profiledisp', args=[self.request.user.username])
```